# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel-loader' in 'C:\Users\durgat\reactApp'

Tags: reactjs

```
{
  "name": "reactApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue , i am still getting this issue after doing many changes like , i degraded the babel to lowest version & i installed npm using this command and also i did many changes but there is no result.
And  **webpack.config.js file**

```
 const path = require('path');
  const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
           entry: './main.js',
           output: {
           path: path.join(__dirname, '/bundle'),
           filename: 'index_bundle.js'
             },
            devServer: {
            inline: true,
            port: 8080
             },
            module: {
                rules: [
                      {
                           test: /\.jsx?$/,
                           exclude: /node_modules/,
                           loader: 'babel-loader',
                           query: {
                           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                                 }
                       }
                      ]
                    },
           plugins:[
                 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                 template: './index.html'
             })
          ]
   }
```

Comment: Share ```webpack.conf.js``` file

Answer (score 0):

i think this could help as i dont know what is webpack file configration
but you can give it try in your webpack file

```
resolveLoader: {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
}
```

please share your webpack.config file

Comment: resolveLoader: {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
}   I added this code to my webpack.config file but its not working.The error is --->Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.resolveLoader has an unknown property 'root'.

Comment: your webpack file also seems fine...delete your node modules folder ,package**lock**.json ,yarn.lock (if have) file than run npm install .

Comment: Yes i tried as you said even though getting error .Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: use path.resolve instead of path.join than try and please configure your webpack.config file according to this[ https://webpack.js.org/configuration/ ] as you are using **4.29** .it will help you